# how to aligh the text between two adjacent html elements

Tags: css

Please see:

http://jsfiddle.net/DCESS/6/

How do I get the two texts to align? Why are they misaligned in the first place?

Details:

There is two texts in there. "by" and "jamie goodhall", I want these two to be horizontally aligned. The way they are, "by" is displayed a little lower that "jamie goodhall".

Many thanks!

Comment: @punit I edited the question with more details.

Comment: means you want the y (from baseline) should be aligned as the height of the other text

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCESS/21/) is that you wish to do?

Comment: @punit your solution solved the problem :) please write it up as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:inline-block` from your `span`

### http://jsfiddle.net/DCESS/10/

OR

Give both text `display:inline-block` like this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/DCESS/11/

Comment: Thanks! but can't do that.  I will lose the ellipsis effect

Comment: Adding display:inline-block did not do the trick. See http://jsfiddle.net/DCESS/19/

Comment: I did, you had a typo in it. The typo broke the ellipsis.  The point of the ellipsis is to put ... after an abbreviated text if the full text is too long for the html element in it. I need the ellipsis functionality.  After fixing the typo the misalignment reappeared. see http://jsfiddle.net/DCESS/20/

Answer (score 0):

As per the above answer and your comments to the answer, write only

```
display:inline
```

for your span

Comment: that defeats the purpose of using the ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

add `vertical-align: top;` to your span

Comment: they are still not aligned. now the y is slightly above the name